# Scala/Java interop: class type not converted?

Tags: scala, interop, typechecking

The javafx api is defined like this:

```
void addListener(ChangeListener<? super java.lang.Boolean> listener)
```

The following code..

```
new TextArea().focusedProperty.addListener(new ChangeListener[Boolean]() {
  def changed(observable: ObservableValue[_ <: Boolean], oldValue: Boolean, newValue: Boolean) {
  }
})
```

..gives this error:

> overloaded method value addListener with alternatives:
>   (javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener[_ >: java.lang.Boolean])Unit 
>   (javafx.beans.InvalidationListener)Unit cannot     be applied to
>   (java.lang.Object with javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener[Boolean])

If I use `java.lang.Boolean` instead of `Boolean`, it works, but not with scala's Boolean. Why is that? Is it possible to use this api without having to type the fully qualified name?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that in Scala, `Boolean <: AnyVal <: Any`, while `java.lang.Boolean <: AnyRef <: Any`.  Since `<? super java.lang.Boolean>` means `java.lang.Boolean` or *any* superclass of it, you must fall into the `AnyRef` side of things.  Unboxing is not enough; `Boolean` still places you on the `AnyVal` side of the type hierarchy even if you would box it into a `java.lang.Boolean`.