# Filter users values on TextField input after a BindDirectional strategy betwen a Slider and min/max TextField

Tags: scala, data-binding, slider, javafx-2, javafx

Using two `TextField` : `texMin` and `texMax` , i want to limit min and max values of my doubleSlider control (cf the custom ui control `DoubleSlider` here : http://code.google.com/p/javafx-widgets/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk%2FDoubleSlider%2Fsrc%2Fdouble_slider )

The DoubleBinded with StringConverter (double to string) works perfectly, but now i don't know how can i filter to get only correct values entered by user in the two `TextField` after it `ENTER` keypress..

I don't know if a `setOnKeyReleasedEvent` filter on value entered by user can work with  a `bindBidirectional` on properties. I think the `bindBidirectional` bypass my filter (fire an event each time the text change), but i'm not sure.

```
    def sliderBlockFactory(slider: DoubleSlider): HBox = {
      val minText = new TextField()
      val maxText = new TextField()
      minText.setText(slider.getValue1().toString)
      maxText.setText(slider.getValue2().toString)

      slider.value1Property().addListener(
        new ChangeListener[Number]() {
          override def changed(ov: ObservableValue[_ <: Number], old_val: Number, new_val: Number) {
            if (new_val.doubleValue() == null) {
              minText.setText("")
            } else {
              minText.setText(new_val.doubleValue().toString())
            }
          }
        })

      slider.value2Property().addListener(
        new ChangeListener[Number]() {
          override def changed(ov: ObservableValue[_ <: Number], old_val: Number, new_val: Number) {
            if (new_val.doubleValue() == null) {
              maxText.setText("")
            } else {
              maxText.setText(new_val.doubleValue().toString())
            }
          }
        })

      minText.setPrefWidth(40)
      maxText.setPrefWidth(40)

      val converter: StringConverter[_ <: Number] = new DoubleStringConverter()

      Bindings.bindBidirectional(minText.textProperty(), slider.value1Property(), converter.asInstanceOf[StringConverter[Number]])
      Bindings.bindBidirectional(maxText.textProperty(), slider.value2Property(), converter.asInstanceOf[StringConverter[Number]])

      val uiSliderBlock = new HBox()
      uiSliderBlock.getChildren.addAll(minText, slider, maxText)
      uiSliderBlock
    }

    def doubleSliderFactory(min: Double, max: Double): DoubleSlider = {
      val slider = new DoubleSlider()

      slider.setMin(min)
      slider.setMax(max)
      slider.setShowTickLabels(true)
      slider.setShowTickMarks(true)
      slider.setMajorTickUnit(50)
      slider.setMinorTickCount(25)
      slider.setSnapToTicks(true)
      slider.setPrefWidth(100)
      slider.setBlockIncrement(10)

      slider
    }

val myDoubleSlider = sliderBlockFactory(doubleSliderFactory(0.0, 100.0))
```

**UPDATE 1 :**

Thanks to comments, i modify my code source.
I giveup DoubleStringConverter because my use case is too complex.
I also translate java source code given in comments url into scala :

```
class DoubleTextField(var minValue: Double, var maxValue: Double, val initialValue: Double) extends TextField {

  require(minValue < maxValue, "DoubleField min value " + minValue + " greater than max value " + maxValue)
  require(maxValue > minValue, "DoubleField max value " + minValue + " less than min value " + maxValue)
  //require(!((minValue <= initialValue) && (initialValue <= maxValue)), "DoubleField initialValue " + initialValue + " not between " + minValue + " and " + maxValue)

  val value: DoubleProperty = new SimpleDoubleProperty(initialValue)

  //scala parsing
  def parseDouble(s: String) = try {
    Some(s.toDouble)
  } catch {
    case _ ⇒ None
  }

  def getValue() = value.getValue()

  def setValue(newValue: Double) = value.setValue(newValue)

  def valueProperty(): DoubleProperty = value

  setText(initialValue.toString())

  val doubleField: DoubleTextField = this

  // make sure the value property is clamped to the required range
  // and update the field's text to be in sync with the value.
  value.addListener(new ChangeListener[Number]() {
    override def changed(observableValue: ObservableValue[_ <: Number], oldValue: Number, newValue: Number) {
      if (newValue == null) {
        doubleField.setText("")
      } else {
        if (newValue.doubleValue() < doubleField.minValue) {
          value.setValue(doubleField.minValue)
          return
        }

        if (newValue.doubleValue() > doubleField.maxValue) {
          value.setValue(doubleField.maxValue)
          return
        }

        if (newValue.doubleValue() == 0 && (textProperty().get() == null || "".equals(textProperty().get()))) {
          // no action required, text property is already blank, we don't need to set it to 0.
        } else {
          doubleField.setText(newValue.toString())
        }
      }
    }
  })

  // restrict key input to numerals.
  this.addEventFilter(KeyEvent.KEY_TYPED, new EventHandler[KeyEvent]() {
    override def handle(keyEvent: KeyEvent) {
      if (!"0123456789".contains(keyEvent.getCharacter())) {
        keyEvent.consume()
      }
    }
  })

  // i don't want a realtime change on my textfield,
  // so i prefer a validate method like focusedProperty (see below)
  /*this.textProperty().addListener(
    new ChangeListener[String]() {
      override def changed(observableValue: ObservableValue[_ <: String], oldValue: String, newValue: String) {
        if (newValue == null || "".equals(newValue)) {
          value.setValue(0)
          return
        }

        parseDouble(newValue) match {
          case Some(d: Double) ⇒
            if (doubleField.minValue > d || d > doubleField.maxValue) {
              textProperty().setValue(oldValue)
              value.set(oldValue.toDouble)
            } else {
              value.set(d)
            }
          case _ ⇒ oldValue //reset to old value
        }

      }
    })*/

  // Detect a change in focus on the text field.. If we lose the focus we take appropriate action
  // problem with boolean : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11377350/scala-java-interop-class-type-not-converted
  this.focusedProperty().addListener(
    new ChangeListener[java.lang.Boolean]() { db ⇒
      override def changed(observable: ObservableValue[_ <: java.lang.Boolean], oldValue: java.lang.Boolean, newValue: java.lang.Boolean) {
        if (!newValue) {
          parseDouble(doubleField.textProperty().get()) match {
            case Some(d: Double) ⇒
              if (doubleField.minValue > d || d > doubleField.maxValue) {
                textProperty().setValue(doubleField.minValue.toString)
                value.set(textProperty().get().toDouble)
              } else {
                value.set(d)
              }
            case _ ⇒ println("error") //reset to old value
          }
        }
      }
    })

}
```

The corrected code source for `DoubleSlider` update by `DoubleTextField` :

```
// inspired by :
// https://gist.github.com/1962045
// https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14138082/java-fx-bidirectional-bindings-of-different-properties
// https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=2311243

def sliderBlockFactory(slider: DoubleSlider): HBox = {
  val minText = new DoubleTextField(slider.getMin, slider.getMax, slider.getMin)
  val maxText = new DoubleTextField(slider.getMin, slider.getMax, slider.getMax)

  slider.value1Property().addListener(
    new ChangeListener[Number]() {
      override def changed(ov: ObservableValue[_ <: Number], old_val: Number, new_val: Number) {
        if (new_val.doubleValue() == null) {
          minText.setText("")
        } else {
          //set new min value of maxText
          maxText.minValue = new_val.doubleValue()

        }
      }
    })

  slider.value2Property().addListener(
    new ChangeListener[Number]() {
      override def changed(ov: ObservableValue[_ <: Number], old_val: Number, new_val: Number) {
        if (new_val.doubleValue() == null) {
          maxText.setText("")
        } else {
          //set new max value of minText
          minText.maxValue = new_val.doubleValue()

        }
      }
    })

  minText.setPrefWidth(40)
  maxText.setPrefWidth(40)

  /*val converter: StringConverter[_ <: Number] = new DoubleStringConverter()
  Bindings.bindBidirectional(minText.textProperty(), slider.value1Property(), converter.asInstanceOf[StringConverter[Number]])
  Bindings.bindBidirectional(maxText.textProperty(), slider.value2Property(), converter.asInstanceOf[StringConverter[Number]])
  */

  minText.valueProperty().bindBidirectional(slider.value1Property())
  maxText.valueProperty().bindBidirectional(slider.value2Property())

  val uiSliderBlock = new HBox()
  uiSliderBlock.getChildren.addAll(minText, slider, maxText)
  uiSliderBlock
}

def doubleSliderFactory(min: Double, max: Double): DoubleSlider = {
  val slider = new DoubleSlider()

  slider.setMin(min)
  slider.setMax(max)
  slider.setShowTickLabels(true)
  slider.setShowTickMarks(true)
  slider.setMajorTickUnit(50)
  slider.setMinorTickCount(25)
  slider.setSnapToTicks(true)
  slider.setPrefWidth(100)
  slider.setBlockIncrement(10)

  slider
}

  val myDoubleSlider = sliderBlockFactory(doubleSliderFactory(0.0, 100.0))
```

Result :)

[image]

This code works, values for min and max of each slider controls are updated correctly, but as you can see, when focus is left and if value are bad **i can't retrieve the old value with focused event**. My question is simple, is there any way to get the old values in the textField without using `changeListener` on `textProperty` ?

**Update 2 :**

I found my answer here :

[Undo behavior on textField value based on value verification after focus lost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14707550/undo-behavior-on-textfield-value-based-on-value-verification-after-focus-lost)

Comment: I created a [sample solution](https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?messageID=10692669) earlier to bind between a Slider and TextField, please take a look at that and see if it helps solve your issue.

Comment: Thanks @jewelsea i'm already based my code on your sample ... :] i post question here to see if there is another way to do that, but it seems we're alone ... I found another path to do that here : https://github.com/fxexperience/code/tree/master/FXExperienceControls/src/com/fxexperience/javafx/scene/control

Comment: @jewelsea i update my source code with a first working answer, but i need your help about retrieving old values for textField (see update 1)

Comment: @reyman64 why you define `var value: DoubleProperty` in `DoubleTextField` instead of `val`? I found that fx properties are so nice as to allow for an immutable reference, a singularity in java!

Comment: @pagoda_5b you're right, it's a mistake, i update source code :)

Comment: @jewelsea i found my answer with another post/question, thanks for helping.