# Undo behavior on textField value based on value verification after focus lost

Tags: scala, event-handling, javafx-2, textfield, undo

I post new question based on this previously code posted here ([Filter users values on TextField input after a BindDirectional strategy betwen a Slider and min/max TextField](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14693177/filter-users-values-on-textfield-input-after-a-binddirectional-strategy-betwen-a))

My goal is simple, what is the best way to undo wrong `TextField` value (based on custom verification) after user lost the focus event on my value.

Only way is to access the oldValue before user overwrite with another focus event ?

Actually i have this simple code :

```
val myTextField = new TextField ()

def parseDouble(s: String) = try {
  Some(s.toDouble)
} catch {
  case _ ⇒ None
}

myTextField.focusedProperty().addListener(
  new ChangeListener[java.lang.Boolean]() { 
    override def changed(observable: ObservableValue[_ <: java.lang.Boolean], oldValue: java.lang.Boolean, newValue: java.lang.Boolean) {
      if (!newValue) {
        parseDouble(myTextField.textProperty().get()) match {
          case Some(d: Double) ⇒  // test on the double value entered by user
          case _ ⇒ // code to reset to old value ??
        }
      }
    }
  })
```

**Update 1 :**

I find discussion here : https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=2382472  about **undo functionnality for TextField/TextArea** and other source code about `TextInputControlBehavior` : https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=2438759&tstart=45

I find description of undo behavior implemented into javafx 2.2 here http://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-7547 but i cannot find sample code...

**Update 2 :**

I find a post for public undo control API (roadmap fixed for 2.2.6) for `TextInputControl` here : http://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-26575

`TextInputBehaviorControl` can be see here : https://bitbucket.org/shemnon/openjfx-rt/src/6696e9cea59c401d2637d82f9cf96a515d210203/javafx-ui-controls/src/com/sun/javafx/scene/control/behavior/TextInputControlBehavior.java

**Update 3 :**

***Tadam !***

Finally i found an horrible way to do that, i hope public API is for 2.2.6 version of javaFX ...

```
    val myTextField = new TextField ()
    
    def parseDouble(s: String) = try {
      Some(s.toDouble)
    } catch {
      case _ ⇒ None
    }
    

  myTextField.focusedProperty().addListener(
    new ChangeListener[java.lang.Boolean]() { db ⇒
      override def changed(observable: ObservableValue[_ <: java.lang.Boolean], oldValue: java.lang.Boolean, newValue: java.lang.Boolean) {
        if (!newValue) {
          parseDouble(myTextField.textProperty().get()) match {
            case Some(d: Double) ⇒
              if (myTextField.minValue > d || d > myTextField.maxValue) {
                doubleField.getSkin.asInstanceOf[TextInputControlSkin[_, _]].getBehavior.asInstanceOf[TextInputControlBehavior[_]].callAction("Undo")
              } else {
                // Here you change value property of textField
              }
            case _ ⇒ myTextField.getSkin.asInstanceOf[TextInputControlSkin[_, _]].getBehavior.asInstanceOf[TextInputControlBehavior[_]].callAction("Undo")
          }
        }
      }
    })
```

I validate the answer if anybody find a better way to do that :)

Comment: Sounds like you already have the answer.

Comment: @Andy-till I'm not expert in javafx, or ui with event building :/ I search proper way to do this behavior, but if it's the only way to do that, i consider posting the source code here to help community. I edit with some path for discussion..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as I am currently working on a JavaFX with Scala solution too, I would like to try your example, but I can't get it compiled. Specifically `doubleField` and `value.set` are unknown!

I have some hints - 
First: there is an obvious code duplication, that could be easily solved by adding a condition to the case - the first case only holds if the condition (d in range) is fulfilled

```
case Some(d: Double) if (doubleField.minValue <= d && d <= doubleField.maxValue) ⇒
  value.set(d)
case _ ⇒ 
  doubleField.getSkin.asInstanceOf[TextInputControlSkin[_, _]].getBehavior.asInstanceOf[TextInputControlBehavior[_]].callAction("Undo")
```

Second: provide a wrapper for anonymous inner classes in Java - for instance the above ChangeListener could be wrapped like this:

```
implicit def unit2ChangeListener[T](f: (ObservableValue[_ <: T], T, T) => Unit) =
  new ChangeListener[T] {
    override def changed(observable: ObservableValue[_ <: T], oldValue: T, newValue: T) {
      f(observable, oldValue, newValue)
    }
}
```

These implicit conversions could be hidden in a util class (along with a nice unit2EventHandler) and imported to your application.
This would lead to something a bit more readable (but still a little painful):

```
myTextField.focusedProperty().addListener(
  (observable: ObservableValue[_ <: java.lang.Boolean], 
     oldValue: java.lang.Boolean, newValue: java.lang.Boolean) =>
     if (!newValue) { ... }
)
```

Probably [ScalaFx](http://code.google.com/p/scalafx/) already provides something like this, but I haven't tried it yet.

Comment: Hi @michael_s, thanks for hints, and sorry for bad copy/paste, i update the source code : `doubleField` = `myTextField` .. If you want to see the real code source sample which work, and if you want to make some revision on it, thanks for the help in this hard way scala + javafx :) https://gist.github.com/reyman/4753927